# how to find the telnet ip address and port number of hosts running in eve-ng VM?

Tags: telnet

I am running an eve-ng VM, and running a couple of nodes (routers) in it. The common problem is, when I click on the nodes, it opens its console in the browser. I installed the client side pack, but same problem. I want to know if it is possible to know explicitly the telnet IP address and port number of hosts running in eve-ng so that I can telnet using the telnet client program. I googled for this simple info, but could not find any promising solution/answer to this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: Could you provide the commands you're executing if any? Which packages do you use in detail in which version?